# EntityFramework Many to Many get link

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following models:

```
public class Step {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Workflow Workflow { get; set; }
    public List<StepOption> Options{ get; set; }

    internal StepDto toDto() {
        return new StepDto {
            Id = this.Id, 
            Name = this.Name,
        };
    }
}
```

and

```
public class StepOption {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
}
```

So as you can see there is a many to many relationship between `Steps` and `StepOptions`.

When I run the database seeder, with the following seed:

```
var workflow = new Workflow {Id = 1,  Name = "Some Workflow" };

context.Workflows.AddOrUpdate(w => w.Name, workflow);

var accept = new StepOption { Id = 1 ,Name = "Accept" };
var reject = new StepOption {Id = 2, Name = "Reject" };
var advies = new StepOption {Id = 3, Name = "Advies" };
context.StepOptions.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, accept, reject, advies);

var step1 = new Step {Id = 1, Name = "Start", Workflow = workflow, Options = new List<StepOption> { accept } };
var step2 = new Step { Id = 2, Name = "Validatie Bouwheer", Workflow = workflow, Options = new List<StepOption> { accept, reject } };
var step3 = new Step { Id = 3, Name = "Controlling1", Workflow = workflow };
var step4 = new Step { Id = 4, Name = "Adviezen", Workflow = workflow };
var step5 = new Step {Id = 5, Name = "Ondersteuning", Workflow = workflow };
var step6 = new Step { Id = 6, Name = "Directie", Workflow = workflow };
var step7 = new Step { Id = 7, Name = "Controlling2", Workflow = workflow };
var step8 = new Step { Id = 8, Name = "Reject", Workflow = workflow };
var step9 = new Step { Id = 9, Name = "Finish", Workflow = workflow };
context.Steps.AddOrUpdate(s => s.Id,
    step1, step2, step3, step4, step5, step6, step7, step8, step9
);
```

There are now 3 columns in the DB:

1. Steps
2. StepOptions
3. StepOptionsSteps

But now I was wondering how I could access the `StepOptions` from a `Steps` Object, It's always null, although in the DB the `StepOptionsSteps` are linked correctly

Comment: you need `virtual` modifier for your `Options` property in `Step` class. That way the lazy loading mechanism can work correctly. Otherwise you need to use `Include` to eager-load the `StepOption` together with `Step`.

Comment: @Hopeless yep that was correct, do you want to post it as answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I'm glad it helped but I would not like to add an answer, it's really trivial. If you want you can delete your question but keeping the question here is also OK (the comments are always helpful if searchers take care about them).